# Cannot create an ECS Service using Terraform on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an ECS service using Terraform. I have some modules defined to create some necessary resources (like the alb, vpc, subnets, etc). All of those have been created successfully, but the `aws_ecs_service` is not being created.

This is the Terraform code I'm using:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "main" {
  family                   = "task-definition"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.fargate_cpu
  memory                   = var.fargate_memory

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name    = "container-definition"
      image   = var.container_image
      cpu     = var.fargate_cpu
      memory  = var.fargate_memory
      command = ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
      port_mappings = [
        {
          container_port = var.app_port
          host_port      = var.app_port
        }
      ]
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group         = "/ecs/task-definition"
          awslogs-region        = var.aws_region
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
}

module "load_balancer" {
  source = "../alb"

  vpc_id             = var.vpc_id
  app_port           = var.app_port
  public_subnets_ids = var.public_subnets_ids
  health_check_path  = "/"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name            = "testing-service"
  cluster         = var.ecs_cluster_id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.main.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [module.load_balancer.sg_id]
    subnets          = var.private_subnet_ids
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = module.load_balancer.alb_tg_arn
    container_name   = "container-definition"
    container_port   = var.app_port
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.load_balancer
  ]
}
```

I'm fully aware that fragment of code is not enough to reproduce the problem, but I have not been able to make a smaller example reproducing the problem. If you need the rest of the files, I can create a public repo or something like with the rest of the code.

The error I'm getting is:

```
╷
│ Error: error creating testing-service service: error waiting for ECS service (testing-service) creation: InvalidParameterException: The container container-definition did not have a container port 8000 defined.
│ 
│   with module.service.aws_ecs_service.main,
│   on service/main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "main":
│   47: resource "aws_ecs_service" "main"
```

### Update

Taking a look at the generated resources, I have seen that the port mapping has not been generated! Even though I have it specified in the terraform code:

[image]

That's a screenshot from the task definition created by that code.

Comment: You hardcoded port `8000` in your python command, and used `var.app_port` elsewhere. Do they match ?

Comment: Yes, that's something I have to change, but they match

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your container definition. Instead of this:

```
      port_mappings = [
        {
          container_port = var.app_port
          host_port      = var.app_port
        }
      ]
```

You should have:

```
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = var.app_port
          hostPort      = var.app_port
        }
      ]
```